# Sort list using every second element

Tags: python

I have a list as following:

```
['Pizza', '1', 'Apple', 2, 'Pizza', '1', 'Orange', '5', 'Pear', '4']
```

And I want to sort it according to every second element in the list, so the output would be the following:

> ['Pizza', '1', 'Pizza', '1', 'Apple', 2, 'Pear', '4', 'Orange', '5']

How can I do this?

Comment: you should start by grouping the list into equally sized chunks or not storing them this way in the first place, having this loose coupling with your data is a bad place to start regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group the list into tuples:

```py
mylist = ['Pizza', '1', 'Apple', 2, 'Pizza', '1', 'Orange', '5', 'Pear', '4']
grouped_list = [(k, v) for k, v, in zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2])]
```

sort them by value:

```py
sorted_list = sorted(grouped_list, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

gives:

```
[('Pizza', 1), ('Pizza', 1), ('Apple', 2), ('Pear', 4), ('Orange', 5)]
```

back into a list:

```py
sum([[k, v] for k, v in sorted_list], [])
```

Comment: This still returns a list of tuples, not a flat list. The real issue is the creation of this list in the first place at which point the sorting of a nested list becomes a duplicate

Comment: but as @Sayse says: maybe reconsider your storing approach in the first place :)

Comment: I cant remake it, my real list is something like this: `['Order1', ['Pizza', '1', 'Apple', 2, 'Pizza', '1', 'Orange', '5', 'Pear', '4'], 'Order2', ['Pizza', '1', 'Pear', 4, 'Pizza', '1']]`

Answer (score 0):

1. build tuples
2. sort
3. rebuild the list by flattening

```py
data = ["Pizza", "1", "Apple", "2", "Pizza", "1", "Orange", "5", "Pear", "4"]
result = [
    item
    for pair in sorted(
        [(data[i], data[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(data), 2)],
        key=lambda item: item[1],
    )
    for item in pair
]
assert result == ["Pizza", "1", "Pizza", "1", "Apple", "2", "Pear", "4", "Orange", "5"]
```